# Residue class of a huge repunit modulus a huge number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Given a number with only 1: `X = 1111...1` (`N` times 1 in total), and another number `M`, I want to calculate `X % M` (the remainder when `X` is divided by `M`).

My approach is to calculate `Y % M` where `Y = 1, 11, 111, ...`until reached the number with `sqrt(N)` times 1, and the algorithm is `O(sqrt(N))`. I wonder whether there is a O(log(N)) algorithm? `N` is at the level of `10^16`, and `M` is at the level of `10^9` in this problem.

Comment: **Hint:** If $ M=10^9$  then $ X\pmod M \equiv X \pmod {10^9} $. You only need to worry about the last 9 digits of X.

Comment: I think the OP was meaning that $M$ has roughly the size of $10^9$, and not that it is *exactly* $10^9$. Otherwise, everything is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Since $X=\frac{10^N-1}{9}$ and we can find the inverse of $9$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/M\mathbb{Z})^*$ in $O(\log M)$ time with the [extended Euclidean algorthm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we just need to find $10^N\pmod{M}$. This can be done in $O(\log N)$ time with the [repeated squaring algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

If you know the factorization of $M$ or a large portion of primes dividing $M$, you can even improve the constants with a careful use of the Chinese remainder theorem and the Fermat's little theorem.

For example, assume that we want to find $\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}\pmod{222}$.

Since $222=2\cdot 3\cdot 37$, we only need to find:
$$10^{100}\pmod{2},\quad 10^{100}\pmod{27},\quad 10^{100}\pmod{37}.$$
Since $\varphi(27)=18$ and $\varphi(37)=36$,
$$10^{100}\equiv 10^{10} \equiv ((10^2)^2\cdot 10)^2\equiv 10\pmod{27},$$
$$10^{100}\equiv 10^{28} \equiv 10\pmod{37}$$
(as it is natural since $27\cdot 37=999|(10^3-1)$), hence:
$$\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}\equiv 1\pmod{2},$$
$$\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}\equiv 1\pmod{3},$$
$$\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}\equiv 1\pmod{37},$$
and, putting this relations back together:
$$\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}\equiv 1\pmod{222}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible that there is no modular inverse? like the inverse of 3 mod 9?

Comment: Clearly yes, if $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$ there is no inverse of $a\pmod{b}$. This is the reason for which i took $10^{100}\pmod{27}$ to compute $\frac{10^{100}-1}{9}\pmod{3}$.

Comment: I'm sorry that i still don't quite catch it, do you mean you will use (mod a*b ) if a,b are not co-prime? What is the principle behind this plz?

Comment: More or less: I mean that in order to find $\frac{a^b-1}{c}\pmod{d}$, where $c|(a^b-1)$, I look for $(a^b-1)\pmod{cd}$.